# How to set atomic32 value?

Tags: c++, macos, operating-system

We need to implement assign functionality for the atomic32 variable. But from the mac document: [Atomic](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/OSAtomicCompareAndSwapPtr.3.html) there is no assign function. So can anyone show how to implement it.

Comment: A 32 bit write on a x86 processor is atomic. It's read/increment/write etc that's not.

Comment: Confused about `read/increment/write etc that's not`. I assume both read/write will be atomic. Is that correct? And how about ARM?

Comment: Read is atomic, write is atomic, but read/modify/write is not.

Comment: @JonathanPotter It may be atomic implementation-wise, but it does not qualify as an atomic operation from the C++ perspective. Which means it doesn't introduce inter-thread visibility syncrhonisation etc.

Comment: 32-bit aligned reads and 32-bit aligned writes are atomic on x86 platforms. However, even though they do provide memory visibility guarantees at assembly-language level, these don't "flow through" to the C++ code because of compiler optimizations. What compiler are you using? Maybe it has atomic intrinsics you can use. What semantics do you need? Be as precise as you can.